# Is there any reason not to unpack simple values in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Let's say I do `unpack(4)` or `unpack("hello world")`. Are there any unexpected behaviors to this?

Reason is something like this:

```
function a(bool)
  if bool then
    return {1, 2}, "foo"
  else
    return 1, "foo"
  end
end

function b(x, z)
end

function b(x, y, z)
end

i, j = a(???)
b(unpack(i), j) -- is this ok?
```

Comment: did it cross your mind that you could just run the code and see what happens instead of asking what happens? a much better way to learn

Comment: `b(unpack(i), j)` is a bad example: result of `unpack(i)` will be adjusted to one value.

Comment: Isn't the easiest way to just return a table in all cases?  So, if there is one value to be returned, do like `return {1},"foo"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unpack(4)` will cause an error

> attempt to get length of a number value

`unpack("hello world")` will return

> nil   nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil

so that's not very useful as well.

unpack is meant for unpacking tables. If you'd work with a recent version of Lua you would notice that it is now `table.unpack()`

Other issues with your code:

Lua does not support overloading functions. Functions are variables.

You write:

```
function b(x, z)
end

function b(x, y, z)
end
```

The first definition is lost once the second definition is processed.
If you use the another notation it will be more clear.
Your code is equivalent to

```
b = function (x, z)
end

b = function (x, y, z)
end
```

and I think you will agree that after

```
b = 3
b = 4
```

`b` will be 4. Same principle...

Comment: Although I see the point you're making about overwriting a function definition, I disagree with 'Lua does not support overloading functions' as it does allow the same effect, in a different way.  For example, being allowed to pass an arbitrary number or type of arguments works effectively the same.  In your example, `function b(x,y,z)` can be made to act as `function b(x,y)` when `z` is `nil`.  And, if an additional version of a function needs to be defined at a later time (i.e., separately), you can always front-end the original function like so: `local b = function (x,y,z) b(x,y) end`

Comment: Corrections: 1) a function is a value, not a variable. A function value, like any other value, is "lost" when it has no references to it. 2) a function definition is an expression that produces a function value. It is code so can never be lost.

Comment: @tonypdmtr "overloading" only makes sense when there is a binding resolution phase (such as by the compiler). In Lua, a name only refers to one thing at anyone one time and in any one place. Each function value can be called with any number of parameters at any time. It deals with the ones it wants in whatever way it wants and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can amend the `unpack` standard function to obtain the desired behavior:

```
local old_unpack = table.unpack or unpack

local function new_unpack(list, ...)
   if type(list) ~= "table" then
      list = {list}
   end
   return old_unpack(list, ...)
end

table.unpack = new_unpack
unpack = new_unpack

-- Usage:
print(unpack(4))
print(unpack("hello world"))
print(unpack(nil))   -- ops!  nothing is printed!
```